# Depth of trees with many NaN features

Tags: xgboost

I have five features that correlate to my target highly but most of the time (>95%) they are NaN. If I have these features, theoretically should I have to increase the depth of the trees in order to capture the probable "IF X5 is present, use this equation"s?